# Browser displaying "Page Not Found" message when error is thrown in an ASP .NET page

Tags: asp.net, iis

When i navigate to an ASP.NET page, the browser displays a "Page Not Found" message. The page exists and is in a virtual directory, I am able to browse it on the IIS on my local development machine. What could be causing this problem on the server?

When i replace one of the class libraries that iam using, with an older version it works. But the page works on my local machine with the new version of the component as well. I have the exact same files on both the server and my development machine.

I have turned custom errors "Off". Is there a way to have the error displayed rather than "Page Not Found".

The page is built using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Can you access any .aspx files on the server, or is it just this one?

Answer (score 1):

You have the ASP.NET extension installed and active?  This is not installed by default in Windows Server 2003.  When this is not active, you will get a 404 for any .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the virtual directory on your server allow scripting? Having scripting off could make the page inaccessible.